# SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to run a query in rails where I get record based on a column being unique, in this case "account_id"

This works perfectly:

```
@comments = @store.comments.where(account_id: @selected_array).where(flagged: true).select('distinct on (account_id) *').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

Except the order is off. When I try to order by creation date:

```
@comments = @store.comments.where(account_id: @selected_array).where(flagged: true).select('distinct on (account_id) *').order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

I get the error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

How do I get the distinct part to still work while ordering by creation date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap it as subquery and then order it.

Raw SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (account) * FROM comments WHERE account_id = 5 AND flagged
) AS sub
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

In rails I think this **might** work (no experience with Ruby or ActiveRecord):

```
store_comments = @store.comments
@comments = store_comments.from(store_comments
                                where(account_id: @selected_array, flagged: true).
                                select('distinct on (account_id) *'))
                          .order(:created_at)
                          .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

You can read more about `from()` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from). I'm not sure what does `@store.comments` syntax means so this could possibly not work.